# 'Bug fixing' a circuit with HiLink HLK PM01 220V->5V converters

Tags: short-circuit, debugging

I soldered a DMX splitter together. However, it does not work.

I'm sure one of the solder connections broke, but I have to find which one. I want to do this with power connected because that is easier to pinpoint the problem (since it is soldered and a bit hard to reach the bottom side where the wires are).

So my plan is to use a multimeter and check the voltage difference between various points. However, I'm afraid I might touch the pins in such a way that a short circuit can exist.

I'm using 5 of these [datasheet-HLK-PM01 power modules](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet-HLK-PM01.pdf). One for the DMX input and 4 for the outputs. What would happen if I cause a short circuit?

The datasheet mentions

> Output over-current protection: 150-200% of the output maximum load
>
> Output short circuit protection: Direct short circuit at the normal output, automatically resume normal operation after a short circuit removal

Does this mean it will not matter if I (for a short time) cause a short circuit?
Or is there a better way to find out the problem? (except checking all possible connections by hand, which I did before soldering everything together)?

(I also have to take into account short circuits for the components I use within the circuit I guess).
Btw, I don't need to use the multimeter directly on the 220V connections, since I can check the 5V/GND of each power module

Comment: fwiw, i had one of those handy little guys shorted overnight and it was fine in the morning. it was a 3.3v, but i doubt that matters...

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation ... I'm busy testing ... and mine also still work (although I try to be very careful).